# How and when does Song of Rest work?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, healing, rests

I am a level 6 bard playing a campaign in 5e. I have the ability "song of rest"

> Beginning at 2nd level, you can use soothing music or oration to help revitalize your wounded allies during a short rest. If you or any friendly creature who can hear your performance regain hit points at the end of the short rest, each of those creatures regains an extra 1d6 hit points (PHB pg 54).

Does this work if they use a potion during the rest? How long is this ability active? What about if a cleric is using a mass heal spell, Or a paladin's Lay on hands? It does say when they regain health points. So can this potentially give them multiple cases of life gain? Or only with the use of Hit Dice?

Song of rest with potion (+1d6) song of rest with hit dice (+1d6) song of rest with mass cure wounds (+1d6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Song of Rest only increases healing from spent hit die

After errata the [Song of Rest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/classes#SongofRest) says:

> If you or any friendly creatures who can hear your performance regain hit points at the end of the short rest **by spending one or more Hit Dice**, each of those creatures regains an extra 1d6 hit points.

The [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) itself says:

> Song of Rest (p. 54). A creature regains the extra hit points only if it spends one or more Hit Dice at the end of the short rest.

So the healing must come specifically from spending hit dice on a short rest and not from any other sources of healing. So every character that spent hit dice on a short rest would get 1d6 extra hit points only.

Answer (score 3):

### Works only with Hit Dice

While the wording is confusing, they key point here is "at the end of the short rest". Drinking a potion or casting a spell happens more *during* the rest, as the end of the rest is not an explicit point in time. In this case it refers to using hit dice, which heal you at the end of the rest:

> A character can spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a short rest
>   (PHB 186)

This was also later clarified in the errata:

> Song of Rest (p. 54). A creature regains the extra hit points only if
>   it spends one or more Hit Dice at the end of the short rest.

Answer (score 2):

### Only hit dice count

The only form of healing that triggers the Song of Rest ability is spending one or more hit dice. This rule, implied in the original rule's "at the end of the short rest" wording, was explicitly stated in the Player's Handbook Errata ([pdf link](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf)):

> **Song of Rest (p. 54).** A creature regains the extra hit points only if it spends one or more Hit Dice at the end of the short rest.